# Storing Stringified JSON in Postgres with Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

We are upgrading our application from Rails 4.2 to Rails 5.0.

We have found that identical requests are generating different sql when inserting in to the database. The database column is JSON and it looks like in Rails 5.0 it is being stored as an escaped string.

Does anyone know how we can ensure the same behaviour between versions?

**Request Params:**

Parameters: {"provider_package_item"=>{"provider_package_id"=>"2", "service_id"=>"6", "service_product_id"=>"17", "provider_price_list_id"=>"12", "provider_price_list_item_id"=>"122", "options"=>"[{\"id\":95,\"title\":\"Finish\",\"value\":{\"id\":\"130\",\"title\":\"Satin\",\"price\":0}},{\"id\":96,\"title\":\"Paper Weight\",\"value\":{\"id\":\"135\",\"title\":\"200GSM\",\"price\":0}},{\"id\":112,\"title\":\"Delivery\",\"value\":{\"id\":\"189\",\"title\":\"Next Day\",\"price\":0}}]"}}

**Database Query in Rails 4.2:**

INSERT INTO "provider_package_items" ("provider_package_id", "service_id", "service_product_id", "provider_price_list_id", "provider_price_list_item_id", "options", "title", "quantity", "price", "options_string", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12) RETURNING "id"  [["provider_package_id", 2], ["service_id", 6], ["service_product_id", 17], ["provider_price_list_id", 12], ["provider_price_list_item_id", 122], ["options", "[{\"id\":95,\"title\":\"Finish\",\"value\":{\"id\":\"130\",\"title\":\"Satin\",\"price\":0}},{\"id\":96,\"title\":\"Paper Weight\",\"value\":{\"id\":\"135\",\"title\":\"200GSM\",\"price\":0}},{\"id\":112,\"title\":\"Delivery\",\"value\":{\"id\":\"189\",\"title\":\"Next Day\",\"price\":0}}]"], ["title", "A4 Brochures"], ["quantity", 50], ["price", 65.0], ["options_string", "/Satin/200GSM/Next Day"], ["created_at", "2017-03-03 05:36:51.613297"], ["updated_at", "2017-03-03 05:36:51.613297"]]

**Database Query in Rails 5.0**

INSERT INTO "provider_package_items" ("title", "service_id", "service_product_id", "provider_price_list_id", "provider_price_list_item_id", "quantity", "options", "options_string", "created_at", "updated_at", "provider_package_id", "price") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12) RETURNING "id"  [["title", "A4 Brochures"], ["service_id", 6], ["service_product_id", 17], ["provider_price_list_id", 12], ["provider_price_list_item_id", 122], ["quantity", 50], ["options", "\"[{\\"id\\":95,\\"title\\":\\"Finish\\",\\"value\\":{\\"id\\":\\"130\\",\\"title\\":\\"Satin\\",\\"price\\":0}},{\\"id\\":96,\\"title\\":\\"Paper Weight\\",\\"value\\":{\\"id\\":\\"135\\",\\"title\\":\\"200GSM\\",\\"price\\":0}},{\\"id\\":112,\\"title\\":\\"Delivery\\",\\"value\\":{\\"id\\":\\"189\\",\\"title\\":\\"Next Day\\",\\"price\\":0}}]\""], ["options_string", "/Satin/200GSM/Next Day"], ["created_at", 2017-03-03 05:30:02 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-03-03 05:30:02 UTC], ["provider_package_id", 2], ["price", 65.0]]

Answer (score 0):

Rails 5 has been updated to comply with RFC 7159. JSON strings e.g. JSON.stringify() from Javascript are now saved as strings rather than a Hash/Array. To maintain the behaviour from previous versions of Rails you need to parse the JSON string before assigning:

```
Model.payload = JSON.parse("{\"key\":\"value\"}")
```

Or you can override the setter method in the model:

```
def payload=(value)
  self[:payload] = value.is_a?(String) ? JSON.parse(value) : value
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/28292

**Observations from kengreeff**

**In Console (Rails 4.2.2)**

```
item = OrderItem.new(options: "{\"key\":\"value\"}")
 => #<OrderItem id: nil, options: {"key"=>"value"}>

item.options
 => {"key"=>"value"} 

item.options.is_a?(String)
 => false 

item.options.is_a?(Hash)
 => true
```

**In Console (Rails 5.0.2)**

```
item = OrderItem.new(options: "{\"key\":\"value\"}")
 => #<OrderItem id: nil, options: "{\"key\":\"value\"}">

item.options
 => "{\"key\":\"value\"}"

item.options.is_a?(String)
 => true 

item.options.is_a?(Hash)
 => false
```

**kamipo have mentioned this**

rails 5

This behavior is because [efaa6e4](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/efaa6e4f79d457c2cdd08cbc56d63bc972a6993c) to fix the issue #[24234](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/24234).
Please use

```
OrderItem.new(options: JSON.parse("{\"key\":\"value\"}")).
```